# Analyze $h_{v}\left(G\right)$ when $G$ is $d$-regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Given that the bipartite graph $G=\left(L\cup R,E\right)$ is $d$-regular and satisfies $|L|=|R|=n$. Given that for every set of vertices $L'\subset L$ of size $|L'|\leq\frac{1}{2}n$ there are at least $|L'|$ Neighbors in $R$. Analyze $h_{v}\left(G\right)$.

I have the following definition:

> Let $G=\left(V,E\right)$ be a graph with $n$ nodes and $1\leq k\le\frac{n}{2}$. The expansion ratio at nodes for sets of size up to $k$ is denoted by $h_{v}\left(G,k\right)$ and is defined as:
> $$
> h_{v}\left(G,k\right)\triangleq\min_{S\subset V,0<|S|\leq k}\frac{|\Gamma\left(S\right)\backslash S|} {|S|}=\min_{S\subset V,0<|S|\leq k}\frac{\partial_{v}\left(S\right)}{|S|}
> $$
> where $\Gamma\left(S\right)$ is the set of neighbors of $S$. In fact, we denote the orthographic language to be:
> $$
> \partial_{v}\left(S\right)\triangleq\Gamma\left(S\right)\backslash S
> $$

But I can't seem to figure how to actually calculate $h_{v}\left(G\right)$ - I understand how the graph looks like in general - but how do I "translate" it into this forumla?

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "analyze"? And by $h_v(G)$ do you mean "$h_v(G,k)$ for each $k$"?

Comment: I am also confused by the sentence starting with "Given...". In a $d$-regular bipartite graph, $|\Gamma(L')| \geq |L'|$ holds for *every* subset $L' \subseteq L$.

Comment: @DánielG. Thanks for the comment. This question is taken from previous exams which I'm trying to solve as part of my preparation to the exam. By $h_v(G)$ I mean $h_v(G)=h_v(G,|V|/2)$. By "analyze" I think they want as to evaluate $h_v(G)$ (for example, if $h_v(G)=0$, then we need to show it). Regarding your second comment - not sure what you mean